# Animate turrets Shooting

Tags: animation

[image: gun turrets]

I want to animate the guns shooting. I'm thinking of moving the gun forwards
and backwards to show shooting. But to do this is very time-consuming. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is this part of a render, an animation, or the BGE?

Comment: It's in Blender Render, and it's an animation.

Comment: This is just a screen capture in solid view.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to create an animation that can be looped.

The most "proper" way to do this is with the Action Editor and Dope Sheet, but I don't understand it well. Someone else might provide that info.

However, you can also use the Graph Editor. If you create an empty that you can animate and slave the turret to that (parent, track to, child of, copy location, vertex parent, lots of options there), you can animate one "vibration" of the turret and then just repeat that same action a number of times. To do that, select the channel that you want to repeat (you might have to do this with each channel), press <kbd>n</kbd>, click `Add Modifier` and choose `Cycles`. To make it vibrate on demand, instead of constantly, animate the `Influence` value. Turn `Influence` to 0.0 when you want it to stop, and then bring it back up to 1.0 when you want a burst of fire.

Note: You don't necessarily have to use an empty, you could just animate the turret, but using an empty lets you isolate the curves for that one animation from other animations you might want to do. I.e. you only add modifiers to the empty's curves, without affecting other animations that you do to the acutal turrets.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll find out about the Action Editor and Dope Sheet.

Comment: Wait, the Action Editor and the Dope Sheet are the same thing!

Comment: Lol, sort of. There are several different views for the Dope Sheet, one is Dope Sheet, and another is Action Editor. I THINK the Dope Sheet view is for arranging actions that have already been created, and the Action Editor view is for creating/editing individual actions... not sure.